# Component is not being display in React

Tags: reactjs

I am following a tutorial in React. I have created my very first component and expecting to see component in my application homepage, but I don't. I am not getting any error either.

In my homePage.Js **(This is a component that I am trying to render)**, I have :

```
var React = require('react');

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="jumbotron">
            <h1>Administration</h1>
            <p>React, React Router.</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

In my Main.js file I have (This main.js serves as the base file for referencing my components):

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var React = require('react');
var Home = require('./components/homePage');

React.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and in my index.html file I have :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Administrator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the app, I see an empty page, and when I check the page source code I can see below HTML in the BODY tag:

```
 <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" async="" defer="">
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: do you get any console errors? what is inside scripts/bundle.js?

Answer (score 2):

You import Home using

```
require('./components/homePage')
```

which is fine for default import, but your's isn't the default.
Use

```
require('./components/homePage').Home
```

or export using

```
module.exports.default = Home;
```

By the way, React.createClass is deprecated. If you want to learn React I recommend the use of ES6 class or function component. Try [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the render method from `react-dom` when mounting the app.

```
ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])
```